# C# equivalent of Java org.json.JSONObject

Tags: c#, xamarin

I'm trying to convert a java project to C#. In the following piece I don't know how to convert the Json part.

```
 Cursor resultSet = helper.openDataBase().rawQuery("Select * from word where wname=?", new String[] {String.valueOf(editable)});
   TextView TextView_FA =  findViewById(R.id.textView_FA);
                 
                if( resultSet.moveToFirst())
                {
                    String str_json = resultSet.getString(2);
                  try {
                        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(str_json);

                        String trans = obj.getJSONArray("ss").optJSONObject(0) .getString("s");

                        TextView_FA.setText(trans);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        TextView_FA.setText(e.getLocalizedMessage());
                    }


                }
                else {

                    TextView_FA.setText("no translation found");
                }
```

This is what I've tried:

```
 EditText EditText_en = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.EditText_en);

            Java.IO.File fil = new Java.IO.File(db_src);
 
            SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.OpenDatabase(fil,null);
            Android.Database.ICursor resultSet = db.RawQuery("Select * from word where wname =? ",new[]{ EditText_en.Text});




            TextView TextView_FA = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.TextView_fa);
            if (resultSet.MoveToFirst())
            {
                String str_json = resultSet.GetString(2);
              
                try
                {
                    
                   // JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(str_json);
                   // String trans = obj.getJSONArray("ss").optJSONObject(0).getString("s");

                    TextView_FA.Text = trans;

                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    TextView_FA.Text = e.Message;
                }


            }
            else
            {

                TextView_FA.Text = "no translation found" ;
            }
```

The two line I've commented is the question.
I tried to use System.Text.Json or System.Json as some of the internet docs has said but VS2019
intellisense doesn't recognize them as a valid library.

Comment: C# has a `JavaScriptSerializer` class that reads and writes Json. Maybe that's what you need?

Comment: To use System.Text.Json, you need to link to the corresponding assembly. In this case, the `System.Text.Json` nuget package.

Answer (score 1):

To use the NewtonSoft.JSon i probably the most common way to Deserialize json and a bit easier (forgiving) than the System.Text.Json. It is also easier to work with JSon if you have a known type. I don't know how your JSon sttring look like but I have made my own example string

```
//[
    // {
        //  color: "red",
        //  value: "#f00"
    // },
    // {
        //  color: "green",
        //  value: "#0f0"
    // },
    // {
        //  color: "blue",
        //  value: "#00f"
    // }
//]
string myJson = "[\r\n\t{\r\n\t\t\"color\": \"red\",\r\n\t\t\"value\": \"#f00\"\r\n\t},\r\n\t{\r\n\t\t\"color\": \"green\",\r\n\t\t\"value\": \"#0f0\"\r\n\t},\r\n\t{\r\n\t\t\"color\": \"blue\",\r\n\t\t\"value\": \"#00f\"\r\n\t}\r\n\t\r\n]";
```

If you have a class or can define it, it will be easier to work with the JSon, but I have created an example without use of the class to

```
public class custColor
{
    public string color { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}
```

Examples with both NewtonSoft and System.Text.Json

```
//NewtonSoft JSON
var arrayOfColors = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<custColor[]>(myJson);
var valueFromArray = arrayOfColors[0].value;    //Will give #f00

var dynamicColorArray = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(myJson);
var valueFromDynArray = dynamicColorArray[0].value; //Will also give #f00

//System.Text.Json
var stjArrayOfColors = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<custColor[]>(myJson);
var stjValueFromArray = stjArrayOfColors[0].value;    //Will give #f00
```